# Can't fix topology

Tags: topology

I have used Blender for a while but I just cannot figure out how to fix this topology problem. After using a Boolean modifer, my topology was fine I thought until I viewed in render mode.
[image]

I know it is because of the two edges selected, but I just can't find a way to get rid of them and keep the boolean shape there.
I've also attached the .blend file:
[image]

Comment: you can't avoid these edges, you need edges to create a hole within a face, and it doesn't seem to cause any problem in render mode (or does it?)

Comment: Gotcha. But for some reason they are causing the faces to glitch. I attached the blend. file if you want but in the image you can see it caused those weird distorted reflections...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't avoid these edges, you need edges to create a hole within a face, and it doesn't seem to cause any problem in render mode.

For your shading problem: You've shade smoothed your object, so it tries to smooth the shading between perpendicular faces, and it gives these artefacts. What you need to do is enable the *Auto Smooth* option and lower down its value under 90° so that it only smooth faces that are under 90°:

[image]

Comment: WOW! It's perfect now, thank you so much!